# AzureRunAsConnection not found

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a AutomationAccount with AzureRunAsConnection created there. I can see it in the portal as well as get it in powershell using `Get-AzureRmAutomationConnection` and i can see the results.[image]

But when i connect from a Runbook ,it throws exception[image]
Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: can you show part of the code that does the auth?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-verify-runas-authentication , i resolved it by using Connect-AzureRmAccount

Comment: You could add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here [Azure Automation Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-verify-runas-authentication) . I used the `Login-AzureRmAccount` and `Add-AzureRmAccount` . Now i found that we should manually update the modules after creating an Automation account and then use `Connect-AzureRmAccount` with the credentials. That worked

Comment: What does that mean? Did you edit the script? What edits did you specifically make?

Comment: This is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73201637/connection-azurerunasconnection-not-found-when-running-backup-azure-sql-datab

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refer to the official docs? I guess you'll find your solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-verify-runas-authentication).

Comment: Seems @HariHaran already provided the same answer in the above comment himself.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice it. Plus he didn't post it as answer.. so yeah :)